# Makefile call itself with identical command line input except prepended string

Tags: makefile

I have a complex, legacy Makefile which I need to run inside of a Docker container.  Essentially, I need the Makefile to call itself again, except I need to prepend "docker run ...".

The end user may make multiple targets, and multiple command line variables and options may also be specified, so I need to duplicate the entire command-line call to make - not just recall each target.

I'm expecting something of the form:

```
<BLACK_MAGIC>:
    docker run my_image make <COMPLETE_ORIGINAL_MAKE_COMMAND_LINE>
```

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Rename the makefile to something else and use the following as a stub

```
FLAGS := $(if $(MAKEFLAGS),-$(MAKEFLAGS))
.SUFFIXES:
.PHONY: all
%:: all ;
all:
    docker run my_image $(MAKE) -f Makefile.old $(FLAGS) $(MAKEOVERRIDES) $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```

- Make removes certain flags from `MAKEFLAGS` in recipes so they need to be copied in the main body
- `.SUFFIXES:` clears the suffix list in case make tries to apply one of its implicit rules
- Make `all` a `.PHONY` target just in case the folder contains a file named `all`
- Make other targets depend on `all` with `%::` to avoid invoking make multiple times
- Since command line variables won't be placed in `MAKEFLAGS` until the recipes are invoked they need to be added in separately with `MAKEOVERRIDES`, we can't use `MAKEFLAGS` directly due to the first point.

Comment: And some documentation regarding the MAKEFLAGS (this is a GNU make extension I think) variable: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html

Comment: @StianSkjelstad `MAKEFLAGS` is part of the POSIX standard, older makes might use `MFLAGS`.